# Cannot create a task when a lead is converted to a contact using Process Builder?

Tags: process-builder

this is my Process builder that i have created and there was no task created for the converted contact = [image]

[image]

Comment: what have you debugged or noted when you convert the lead? Are you sure you want to set the `Assigned to ID`/Owner of the task to the `Contact Id`? Shouldn't it be a user and should the `Contact Id` be the `Name Id`/WhoId?

Comment: I suggest triggering on the converted contact. And not that this cannot be done with process, but I always suggest "go with the flow".